# Google tracking code in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, handlebars.js

Has anyone here tried to include a Google Analytics tracking code to a handlebars template to avoid copy pasting it into a bunch of different pages? I tried it out but for some reason, it won't work: if someone visits a page, it doesn't show up on the dashboard. When I inspect the footer element in the browser, the code appears to be there and there are no errors in the console either.

template.js

```
var footer_template = "Some footer links here"+
                "<script>"+
                  "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){"+
                  "(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),"+
                  "m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)"+
                  "})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');"+
                  "ga('create', 'UA-36406838-2', 'alittlespa.com');"+
                  "ga('send', 'pageview');"+
                "</script>";

var source = footer_template;
footer_template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.querySelector("#footer").innerHTML = footer_template({});
```

document.html

```
<html>
<body>
   Some stuff here
   <footer id="footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any scripting errors. Are you using the correct UA-ID for the property you are viewing?

> "ga('create', '**UA-36406838-2**', 'alittlespa.com');"+

Are you also certain that you are using a Universal Analytics property and not sending data to a Classic Analytics property?

Comment: Yes. When I add this script manually to each html file, it works